# Showing sub-category list when an option select in parent category

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a list of standards (or classes) and when a person selects the standard 9th or 10th I want to show another drop down list where he/she can select specific groups.

Here is the code for first list (classes)

```
<?php
    /*Getting the data to show in drop down list*/
    $sql = $DB_con->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT cls_id, cls_name FROM class ORDER BY cls_id ASC" );
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->fetchAll();
?>
```

And in the form I have displayed the items using `foreach`...

```
<html>
    <form method="post">
        <select name="class">
            <option value="">SELECT CLASS</option>

            <?php
                foreach ($result as $r)
                {
                    echo '<option value="' .
                         $r["cls_id"] .
                         '">' .
                         $r["cls_name"] .
                         '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Now selecting the specific class from first list, I want to show the next list which will have groups.  I have code ready to display the items in the list, but no idea how I'm going to show or hide the second list.

I have more than 6 items in first list and groups (which will appear in next list) are only for 2 of the items from first list.  As you can see, I have used `foreach` to populate the first list and plan to use same code to populate the subcategory list.  I just don't know how on selection of those 2 items sub-category list should appear.

Comment: Start with studying jquery.

Comment: I have tried jquery too, but what with available on internet, I didn't get how to get specific or selected class and basing on this show another list. All the examples were with fixed given values..

Comment: One option is to output all of the different group selectboxes, and then use JS (preferably with jQuery) to show the relevant one and hide the others. Another option is to just have one group selecbox, and then populating it with AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are many options in the selectboxes, I would just output all of the group selectboxes with PHP and then hide and show them with JavaScript.

For the PHP, just loop through all the classes, and for every class add a selectbox with the groups. If you have classes A and B you would want HTML like this:

```
<select name="groups-A" data-class="A" class="group-select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
<select name="groups-B" data-class="B" class="group-select">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Then this jQuery will take care of the hiding and showing:

```
//Run this code when the DOM is ready.
$(function() {
    //Execute the function when the select named class changes.
    $("select[name=class]").change(function() {
        //Hide all of the selectboxes.
        $("select.group-select").hide();
        //Show the selected one.
        var selector = "select[data-class=" + $(this).val() + "]";
        $(selector).show();
    }
    //Trigger the change event so you show the right one to begin with.
    $("select[name=class]").trigger("change");
});
```

You might want to give the class selectbox an ID so you can use `#class` instead of `select[name=class]`. Also, you might want to use this CSS

```
.group-select { display: none; }
```

to avoid having the selectboxes show before the JS runs.

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this code.*

Comment: this seems very viable solution. Let me give it try and see how it goes. I'll update in due time.

Comment: I have tried using this - Please see my edited post.

Comment: Could you put the outputted HTML (not the PHP) and the JS in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? From there I should be able to track down any bugs for you.

Comment: The code works. You had just left an extra `})` at the end, that caused a syntax error. See working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bs81gvL6/). A tip for the future is to *always check the console log when something doesn't work.* Had you done that, it would have told you that you had a syntax error, and it would have taken you at most five minutes to fix.

Comment: Also, I would remove the second edit from your question since it doesn't add anything and is just confusing for future visitors.

Comment: Second edited removed. :)

Yes, code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs81gvL6/) It is however not working on my side, but I'll keep digging and try to make it work.

Much much appreciation for your guidance and help. Stay blessed.